# An Orthogonal Transformation of IID Standard Normal $X$ Is Also IID Standard Normal

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X_1, X_2 ... X_n$ are IID standard normal variables and that $V$ is an orthogonal transformation.  The text is claiming that $Y = VX$ is also IID standard normal because the two joint densities are the same:

$$\begin{split}
P( Y \in \Omega) \ \ = \ \ P(X \in V^{-1}\Omega) \ \ & = \ \ \int_{V^{-1}\Omega} f(x) \, dx \\ & = \ \ \int_\Omega \frac{f(V^{-1}y)}{| \det V |} \, dy \ \ = \ \ \int_{\Omega} f(V^{-1} y) \, dy \\
\\
f(x) \ \ = \ \ f(V^{-1}y) \ \ & = \ \ (2 \pi)^{-n/2}e^{-|V^{-1}y|^2/2} \ \ = \ \ (2 \pi)^{-n/2} e^{-|y|^2/2} \ \ = \ \ f(y)
\end{split}$$

However, each element in $Y$ is still a linear combination of the same $X_1, X_2 \ldots X_n$.  It is in this respect that I'm having some trouble imagining that $Y_1, Y_2 \ldots Y_n$ are also IID standard normal.  Is there another explanation to this (in my view) surprising result?

Comment: Have you thought about it in a concrete example? Say, if $V= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, i.e. $Y_1=(X_1+X_2)/\sqrt{2}$ and $Y_2=(X_1-X_2)/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: The polar coordinates view is perhaps instructive - you can generate a standard normal vector by sampling a radius $R$ according to some density (exercise: work out which), and an independent point on the sphere  $\Theta$ uniformly. The resulting vector $(R, \Theta)$ (in polar coordinates) is standard normal (exercise: prove this). 
Now, an orthogonal transformation maintains the symmetry of the sphere, so applying this does not alter the distribution of $\Theta$. And of course, an orthogonal transformation does not affect the norms of vectors, and so the law of $R$ is also left undisturbed.

Comment: @NicolásVilches:  Indeed, the cross terms cancelled out when I multiplied out $|X|^2 = |V^{-t}Y|^2 = |Y|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid standard normal iff they are jointly standard normal: $$X\equiv(X_1,...,X_n)'\sim N(0,\mathbb{I}_n).$$

Any affine transform of (multivariate) normal is also normal, so $VX$ is normal with mean $V\mathbb{E}[X]=0$ and variance $V\text{Var}(X)V'=VV'=\mathbb{I}_n$ by orthogonality of $V$, implying $(VX)_1,...,(VX)_n$ are iid standard normal.